# If $|X| \leq |Y|$ almost surely, and $Y^2$ has a finite expectation, show that X has a finite expectation.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be discrete random variables, show that if $|X|\leq|Y|$ almost surely ($P\left(\left|X\right|\leq\left|Y\right|\right)=1$), and $Y^2$ has finite expectation, then X has also has finite expectation.

My try: let $A,B$ be the support of $X,Y$, so

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)=\sum_{i\in A}iP\left(X=i\right)\leq\sum_{i\in\left|A\right|}iP\left(\left|X\right|=i\right)\leq\sum_{i\in\left|A\right|}iP\left(\left|X\right|=i\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\right)\leq\mathbb{E}\left(\left|Y\right|\right)
$$
But it is not true that $\mathbb{E}\left(\left|Y\right|\right)\leq\mathbb{E}\left(Y^{2}\right)$, so I am not sure what to do now. I need to show that $|Y|$ has finite expectation, but I am not sure how. I am also not sure that if I show $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)<\infty$ that means that $X $ has finite expectation, is is true? If yes, why?

Comment: can you use Jensen's inequality?

Comment: In general $\mathbb{E}[ (|Y| - \mathbb{E}[|Y|])^2] \ge 0$, since the argument is non-negative. This is of course just the variance, so you get $\mathbb{E}[|Y|] \le \mathbb{E}[Y^2]^{1/2}.$ Also, it is not enough to show that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty,$ you also need to show it is $> -\infty,$ but this is also implied by $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ (why?)

Comment: $0 \le |\mathbb E(X) | \le \mathbb E(|X|) \le \mathbb E(|Y|) = \mathbb E(\sqrt{Y^2})  \le \sqrt{\mathbb E(Y^2)} \lt \infty$

Comment: $\text {GM}\leq \text {AM}$ tells you that $\big \vert Y\big \vert = \Big(1^2 \cdot \big \vert Y\big \vert^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\big(1+Y^2\big)$